# html accept zip file not working

Tags: html

```html
<input type="file" accept=".zip">
```

my code

```
<input type="file" accept=".zip">
```

or

```
<input type="file" accept="application/zip,application/x-zip,application/x-zip-compressed,application/octet-stream">
```

it does not working. I clicked but browser not show dialog to choose file. Anyone help me?

Comment: It simply doesn't do *anything*…?!

Comment: no, when i click "choose File", it does not working. Really all my team tested it.

Comment: Seems to work for me! - See above

Comment: Have you checked the configuration of your browser - this may be a feature that can be disabled

Comment: I really surprise with this situation. I do not think it does not working.

Comment: I realize that my website is running on private, this is reason.

Answer (score 0):

This attribute doesn't works with all browsers:
https://caniuse.com/#search=accept

Comment: I think that in this case the attribute is just ignored - So a file choosing dialog is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I set disabled this option of chrome, it works.

[image]